# UICollectionView's UICollectionReusableView preventing / blocking taps on UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm using a UICollectionView with a Flow Layout.  I've set the header, which is a UICollectionReusableView to behave like so;

```
layout?.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true

...

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

    header.layer.zPosition = -1
    return header
}
```

This gives the desired effect that when scrolling the cells up, the header stays pinned but goes behind the regular cells.

However, if I try to click a UICollectionViewCell that is scrolled toward the top, i.e. so it's technically covering the UICollectionReusableView, the UICollectionViewCell's didSelectItemAt tap event no longer fires until I scroll it back down away from where the header is.  In other words, the UICollectionReusableView is blocking tap gestures, even though it's zPosition is set to -1 and isn't visible.

[image: UICollectionView zIndex issue explained]

Has anyone ever had this issue and how did you fix it?

Comment: I haven't tried that, but it sounds like `header.layer.zPosition = -1` simply pushes the `layer` back, but not the header *view* itself (rather surprised that works at all, really).

Comment: The header "view" is still there as you've pinned it. And visually you've only moved its layer back as DonMag mentioned. It seems like you simply don't want a *header* but some other sort of object instead which you can create in your layout.

Comment: I have found a workaround is to set `header.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` - but if the header contains a UIButton (which mine does) then this will then break the button.  I think my solution is to ditch it all together (stop pinning the header) or toggling `header.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` on scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a Parallax effect to my UICollectionReusableView header.  There are a few Parallax libraries out there, but it's actually really simple - I achieved it using the following code;

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if header != nil {

        let scrollDiff = scrollView.contentOffset.y - self.previousScrollOffset

        let absoluteTop: CGFloat = 0;
        let absoluteBottom: CGFloat = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height;

        let isScrollingDown = scrollDiff > 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.y > absoluteTop
        let isScrollingUp = scrollDiff < 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.y < absoluteBottom

        var newHeight = self.headerHeight
        if isScrollingDown {
            newHeight = max(self.minHeaderHeight, self.headerHeight - abs(scrollDiff))
        } else if isScrollingUp {
            newHeight = min(self.maxHeaderHeight, self.headerHeight + abs(scrollDiff))
        }

        if newHeight != self.headerHeight {
            self.headerHeight = newHeight

            self.collectionView?.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: (self.collectionView?.contentOffset.x)!, y: self.previousScrollOffset)
            self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        }

        self.previousScrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }

}
```

And then to alter the height of the header (which is called when you invalidateLayout());

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height:self.headerHeight)
}
```

The result is that no overlapping ever occurs, but it still gives the desired effect that I was aiming to achieve in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to your Section Header view class:

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

will pass all touches through to the next receiver below - in this case, your collection view cell. If you need an interactive element (such as a button) in the Section Header, you can do:

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let ptInSub = theButton.convert(point, from: theButton.superview)
    if theButton.bounds.contains(ptInSub) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

This *could* give you what you want, although... if the Cell View is covering the Button on the Section Header, and you tap the cell where the button is, the button will take the tap. Should be able to get around that with another `contains(point)` or two...